# htaccess Rewrite Rule REQUEST URI Issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

if site name does not have REQUEST URI then index.php should come
else if URL is example.com/key the file pages.php?tkey=key should come.

When I set this way images in subfolders are not loading

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?page_keytkey=$1 [L]
```

Please advice

Comment: What behaviour occurs vs what are you expecting?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?page_keytkey=$1 [L]` this looks for me like recursive rewrite

Comment: @PålBrattberg styles,images links are redirecting to pages.php

Comment: @AnishJoseph This is a very common problem. If you have a catch-all rule like your pages.php rule, you need to precede it with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to prevent it rewriting actually existing files and directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try preventing the recursive loop that **Peter Szymkowski pointed out**.
Also consider not redirecting existing files as **Michael Berkowski said**.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages.php?page_keytkey=$1 [L]
```

You can read more at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond for example.

Comment: just one more doubt is this mandatory 
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L] ??

Comment: Actually no. That redirect is unneeded if the `DirectoryIndex` directive in apache set correctly